# Activate CSS effect on page load

Tags: css, hover

So this is the code that I am trying to use:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><i class="fas fa-phone fa-5x"></i></div>

<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('.fa-phone').addClass('hvr-buzz');
});
</script>
```

I guess the problem stems from the fact that this effect is triggered on hover, by default, because I am using Hover.CSS ( https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ ).

My goal is to make this effect run infinitely when the page loads, without the user having to hover over it.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the styles below without :hover to your element in the CSS, no JS needed.

```
.hvr-buzz:hover, .hvr-buzz:focus, .hvr-buzz:active {
    -webkit-animation-name: hvr-buzz;
    animation-name: hvr-buzz;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.15s;
    animation-duration: 0.15s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.hvr-buzz {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/xxxEbZz

Comment: Thanks!!! I can't believe how obvious it was, lol!

To those of you wishing to know what the solution is - copy-paste the code (you could even give it whatever class name you want) and that's all it is! You just apply it!